# Laravel route model binding with sorted eager loading?

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, eloquent, eager-loading

I have products which have also comments. This comments can be voted and comments can also have child comments. The comments get loaded via eager loading `$with` which is defined in the `product` model and the child comments get as well loaded via eager loading which is also defined in the `comments` model. The child comments can also be voted (but don't have any child comments).

Product.php (Model)

```
namespace App;

class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * @Protected_variables
     */

    protected $with = [
        'comments',
        'user'
    ];

    /**
     * @Relationships
     */

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

Comment.php (Model)

```
namespace App;

class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * @Protected_variables
     */
     
    protected $with = [
        'children',
        'user'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ChildComment');
    }
        
    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'comments_likes', 'comment_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

I use route model binding to receive my product in the `ProductController.` Here is an example of the route `Route::get('/product/{product}', ['as' => 'product.show', 'uses' => 'ProductController@show']);` and the function `show`:

ProductController@show:

```
public function show(Product $product, Request $request)
{
    if(request()->wantsJson()){
        return response()->json([
            'product' => $product
        ]);
    }

    return view('pages.productDetails')->with([
            'product' => $product
        ]);
}
```

In the `show` function I can now access the `comments` of the product, as well as the `child comments` of the `comments` and all the other relations which get loaded via the `$with` attribute in the models.

Now comes questions. As I already have loaded the relationship, how can I either 1. sort them now or 2. pass the sort arguments to the model to get a sorted relationship back?

When I write `dd($product->comments->sortByDesc('created_at')->toArray());` I get my `product` with the `comments` which are sorted by `created_at`. That's what I want. But I cannot assign the sorted collection to the `product` collection like this `$product->comments = $product->comments->sortByDesc('created_at');` because `$product->comments` is `@property-read`.

I also don't want to do another query and pass this `$product->comments()>orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();` to my response. Because then the eager loading in the model redundant.

Is there a way to 1. either sort the relationship collection or 2. pass the sort arguments to the model to get a sorted relationship back?

I actually want to stick to my route binding model. I know I could pass the sorting arguments and product `id` as arguments and then execute it via `get`. But is there a solution to do that within the model eager loading?

Also, please note I want to sort my comments also by likes and the count of child comments they have. I don't want to sort them only by date, so I need to pass the sort argument to the model when choosing a solution for number 2.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

Use the lazy eager loading with additional sort query.

```
$product->load([
    'comments' => function ($query) { 
        $query->orderBy('created_at')
    }
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default order for a relation or make an entire new relation for it.

```php
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Edit: if you decide to go with a default order and need to remove this another query you can use `reorder()` see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: But this is now a default order as you say. How can I pass the sort arguments? I want to sort by `comment` date, by `comment` likes and by amount of `child comments` per `comment`